# How to use NestedScrollView, SwipeRefreshLayout and WebView together?

Tags: android, webview

Using all the latest libraries. I have a simple WebView inside a CoordinatorLayout fragment. Trying to hide the toolbar when user scrolls sdown.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout       

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/clRootHome"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.bytefury.deliverzz.fragment.HomeFragment">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/srlHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
            android:id="@+id/frag_wv_wv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

However, this doesn't do anything at all. Swipe to refresh works fine.

Out of desperation, when I switch the NestedScrollView and SwipeRefreshLayout, I get a blank, white screen.

Comment: I dont think you need the `NestedScrollView` in there. The webview should handle scrolling just fine.

Comment: I may have been unclear. NestedScrollView is used so the toolbar will hide when webView is scrolling.

Comment: You can achieve that without the `NestedScrollView`. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want your toolbar to be scrollable, refactor your layout into this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clRootHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.bytefury.deliverzz.fragment.HomeFragment">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/srlHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
            android:id="@+id/frag_wv_wv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" />

     </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Now add this to your toolbar layout.

```
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

Comment: When you answer a question, try to make it useful for future visitors, not just for the author. Also be more clear about what you added, don't just give him the code.